# How can combine two or more contentcontrols programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have more ContentControls in mainwindow.XAML like these:

```
<ContentControl Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Ellipse Stretch="Fill" Fill="Red"></Ellipse>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>

<ContentControl Width="50" Height="50" Canvas.Left="241" Canvas.Top="32">
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Stretch="Fill" Fill="Blue"></Rectangle>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>

<ContentControl Width="10" Height="150" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="50">
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Path Data="..."></Path>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

I want to make a ContentControl with ControlTemplate of combine of them. but I want to do this programatically.
How can I do this?
You can see in image what I want if my description is not clear?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReumG.jpg]

Comment: A contentcontrol only has the one content. Thus if the answer has to involve a contentcontrol then you need one thing holds both circle and square. That could be a canvas.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to use Canvas.